# error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'F:\###'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm, react-native

В общем не могу сделать билд, вылезает вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В package.json rnpm нет (в package.json самого модуля, тоже удалял - не помогло)

Интересно, что пишется какой-то файл с названием ### в корень диска, хотя в настройках все нормально, и раньше делалось как положено в myProject/android/app/build/outputs/release/...

**$ react-native info**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже все перепробовал, никак не могу понять в чем проблема! Помогите советом, буду благодарен!

Кстати между прочем, еще стоит "nvm" и несколько версий ноды, может это влияет?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему! Проблема заключалась в названии каталога "### Development", компилятор не мог его корректно прочитать! Странно, но до этого все отлично всегда читалось, но только не в этот раз)))